# Google Firebase not working in iOS App, XCode. Auth.auth.signIn() method not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an iOS app I'm making in XCode, and I am using Google Firebase as the backend. When I run my program, the debug console prints:

> 2021-03-07 13:39:43.783572-0800 Magnet[12265:425578] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed

and then about 5-10 seconds later it gives me these connection errors:

> 2021-03-07 13:39:53.837553-0800 Magnet[12265:425567] Connection 1: received failure notification
>
> 2021-03-07 13:39:53.838667-0800 Magnet[12265:425567] Connection 1: failed to connect 3:-9816, reason -1
>
> 2021-03-07 13:39:53.839105-0800 Magnet[12265:425567] Connection 1: encountered error(3:-9816)

After these connection errors print, I find that Firebase's login method no longer runs the code I wrote after the method, which looks like this in my code:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] authResult, error
    in
    
    //MY CODE THAT NO LONGER RUNS AFTER CONNECTION ERRORS ARE PRINTED
    if error != nil {
        //create account here
        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toRegister", sender: nil)
        print("WRONG! Account doesn't exist")
    } else {
        print("ACCOUNT EXISTS")
        KeychainWrapper.standard.set((authResult?.user.uid)!, forKey: "KEY_UID")
        self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewFeed", sender: nil)
    
        
    }
 }
```

Is my application not set up with Google Firebase correctly? From what I can tell, there is some connection issue preventing my application from connecting to google firebase in order to verify the email and password that was given by the user

Comment: are you using XCode 12? I've read somewhere that Xcode 12 simulator has an issue related to libquic

Comment: Can you provide more details about your environment? The iOS 12 Simulator does indeed have a couple of issues, one of them being that it's not capable of resolving HTTPS sites.

Comment: Yes I'm using XCode 12. Is there someplace I could read more about the known issue with the simulator?